# Rust dependency inversion with nested structs using RC

Tags: struct, rust

I am trying to do some dependecy inversion in Rust. My goal is to create a struct that accepts any other struct instance that complies with a trait.

This wont compile, but is basically what I would like to achieve:

```rust
// Trait for any kind of tool I may use in my work
trait ToolTrait {
  fn do_work(&self);
}

struct Saw {
  size: i32,
}

impl ToolTrait for Saw {
  fn do_work(&self) {
    println!("I'm a saw, size: {}cm", self.size);
  }
}

struct ScrewDriver {
  size: i32,
}

impl ToolTrait for ScrewDriver {
  fn do_work(&self) {
    println!("I'm a screwdriver, size: {}mm", self.size);
  }
}

// Work uses any struct that complies with ToolTrait
pub struct Work {
  tool: ToolTrait,
}

impl Work {
  // We can instantiate Work and set tool to it
  fn new(tool: ToolTrait) -> Work {
    Work { tool }
  }
}

let saw = Saw { size: 30 };
let work_1 = Work::new(saw);
work_1.tool.do_work(); // "I'm a saw, size: 30cm"

let screwdriver = ScrewDriver { size: 4 };
let work_2 = Work::new(screwdriver);
work_2.tool.do_work(); // "I'm a screwdriver, size: 4mm"
```

Now, regarding Rust compiler, we have several error warnings:

```rust
pub struct Work {
  tool: ToolTrait,
}
// trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
```

Ok, lets add `dyn` both in `Work` and `impl Work`:

```rust
pub struct Work {
  tool: dyn ToolTrait,
}
impl Work {
  fn new(tool: dyn ToolTrait) -> Work {
    Work {
      tool: Rc::new(tool),
    }
  }
}
```

Perfect, no error in `Work`. But focusing on `impl Work` we have this error:

```rust
impl Work {
  fn new(tool: ToolTrait) -> Work {
    Work {
      tool: Rc::new(tool),
    }
  }
}
// the size for values of type `(dyn main::ToolTrait + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
```

Makes sense: `Work` can not know what size `tool` will have. But how can I fix it?
I wrapped `dyn ToolTrait` with `std::rc::Rc` as `Rc<dyn ToolTrait>`:

```rust
pub struct Work {
  tool: Rc<dyn ToolTrait>,
}

impl Work {
  // We can instantiate Work and set tool to it
  fn new(tool: Rc<dyn ToolTrait>) -> Work {
    Work { tool }
  }
}
```

This works, but is this the correct way to achieve dependency inversion as we usually do in object oriented programming?

Comment: You can make `Work` _generic_ over the trait: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=937703849379972df9ab6f02c960aa6b

Comment: ...or, you can make `Work` type-erase the dependency: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed74eb3750e9154a478012a19a7fc026

Comment: Tons of thanks! I'm going to study this code, will have questions :)

Comment: The nice thing is that your `main()` and the traits and their implementations are completely unchanged in both snippets. The only thing that changes between static and dynamic dispatch is the implementation of `Work`. Your `Rc` attempt was close to what you need for dynamic dispatch, but there is no reason to use `Rc` (you don't share ownership), `Box` is a much better fit.

Comment: But being the generics option much simpler than the Box, which benefits would have using Box over the generics?

Comment: The advantage of the boxed version is that it completely hides the type of the tool it holds. For example, with the boxed version you could easily create a vector of different tools, it'd just be `Vec<Work>`. In the generic version you could have a vector of saws with `Vec<Work<Saw>>` or a vector of screwdrivers with `Vec<Work<ScrewDriver>>`, but not both saw and screwdriver in the same vector!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your struct **generic** over the tool:

```rust
// Trait for any kind of tool I may use in my work
trait ToolTrait {
    fn do_work(&self);
}

struct Saw {
    size: i32,
}

impl ToolTrait for Saw {
    fn do_work(&self) {
        println!("I'm a saw, size: {}cm", self.size);
    }
}

struct ScrewDriver {
    size: i32,
}

impl ToolTrait for ScrewDriver {
    fn do_work(&self) {
        println!("I'm a screwdriver, size: {}mm", self.size);
    }
}

// Work uses any struct that complies with ToolTrait
pub struct Work<T> {
    tool: T,
}

impl<T: ToolTrait> Work<T> {
    // We can instantiate Work and set tool to it
    fn new(tool: T) -> Work<T> {
        Work { tool }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let saw = Saw { size: 30 };
    let work_1 = Work::new(saw);
    work_1.tool.do_work(); // "I'm a saw, size: 30cm"

    let screwdriver = ScrewDriver { size: 4 };
    let work_2 = Work::new(screwdriver);
    work_2.tool.do_work(); // "I'm a screwdriver, size: 4mm"
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea! Much better, will try this